# no command line interpreter in Browser Console

Tags: firefox, command-line, console, browser-console

According to this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console my browser console (Ctrl+Shift+j) should have command line interpreter but it doesn't. My browser is Firefox stable 69.0.3. Is this feature available only in Firefox Developer Edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just having this problem but found the solution. There is a little note on the [mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) that says:

> NB: The Browser Console command line (to execute JavaScript expressions) is disabled by default. To enable it set the `devtools.chrome.enabled` preference to `true` in about:config, or set the "Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes" (Firefox 40 and later)  option in the developer tool settings.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> - opens up the web developer tools.

<kbd>F1</kbd> - Opens up preferences

Then right at the bottom there's a tick box that says *"Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes"*. This needs to be turned on.